# Create a navbar with memory of previous pages visited

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with mvc, c#, asp.Net , and I have created a navbar that should  have a behaviour similar  to Instagram navbar.
For instance, when someone clicks in Products, the webpage would show all the available products.

[image: nav bar]

If the user clicks, for example, on product one,sub products options would be displayed

[image: sub products]

This behavior would be the same if the user clicks on the sub products options:

[image: subProducts options]

Now, my idea is that, if I am on the SubProducts tab options tab, and click on SubProducts, I would get the parent elements of the last picture.
And if I am on SubProducts (having visited a SubProducts options) and I click on SubProducts Options, I would get the subProducts options item I visited before.
This is the NavBar code, using razor:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("my app", "test1", "aasdfasdfasdfasdf", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @if (User.IsInRole("role"))
            { }
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("SubProducts", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("SubProducts options", "About", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I need a way to change dynamically the links of the navbar.
How can I do it? Thank you again.

**Note:** I would like to make the navbar options to be fixed, always visible to the user. Think of this like the Whatsapp menu, or instagram or facebook for phones.

Comment: I think what you are after is *breadcrumbs*. Search for that online and see if thats what you want.

Comment: Well, I think Bootstrap already have component that you want: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#breadcrumbs. There are much examples everywhere, here you can getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270438/breadcrumb-into-a-navbar-in-bootstrap-3-0-2.

Comment: thank you, is similar to what I want, but in this case I want the navbar items fixed, so the user experience is the same always, for example, in whatsapp, you see always the same options, also in facebook.

Comment: Its actually the same idea as *breadcrumb* but you need to keep the breadcrumbs hidden and only show the tabs. You should also edit your question because *Sub Products* and *Sub Product Options* is confusing. It is not clear what you are asking. Also keep in mind that web ux is different than a native app ux. Your users may find it confusing and odd if your ux is like a native app but it is a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching using the suggestions of Tetsuya Yamamoto and Coding Yoshi, I could find a very interesting Nuget for .net:

[MVCBreadCrumbs](https://github.com/thelarz/MvcBreadCrumbs)

It allows to implement BreadCrumbs easily, without much code, you should try it!